# Spring MVC Request Param

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a login page with form action of **j_security_check**. As of now this form just have two fields namely username
and password. I want to add a new dropdown to this form and collect the selected value in controller using
`@RequestParam`. For some reason I am not able to pass this dropdown value from JSP to my controller as its throwing the 
`exception:  MissingServletRequestParameterException` (Which occurs anytime a request param is missing).
In the code below I added the Visuals dropdown. Do I need to use `Spring:Bind` tag here?
Also on successful login, the control is directed to a controller with request mapping **/controller1.html** and this is where
I am trying to collect the dropdown value.

```
<form name="appLogin" action="j_security_check" method="POST">

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username: </td>
                <td><input id="userName" name="j_username" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password: </td>
                <td><input name="j_password" type="password" value="" /></td>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>Visual: </td>
                <td><Select name="visuals" id="visuals"/>
                      <option value="S1">S1</option>
                      <option value="S2">S2</option>
                      <option value="S3">S3</option>
                      <option value="S4">S4</option>
                    </Select>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In">Sign In</button>
                <input type="submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Controller Code:

```
 @RequestMapping( value = " /controller1.html", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String setupForm( @RequestParam(value = "visuals", required=false) String visuals,
            ModelMap model )
    {
        List<String> studentNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> teacherNames = new ArrayList<String>();


         model.addAttribute("someData", teacherNames);
         model.addAttribute("anotherData", studentNames);

        model.addAttribute("visuals", visuals);

        log.info("Role from Dropdown:  " + visuals);

        return "school/classTen";
    }
```

Comment: and what does the controller method with the @RequestParam look like?

Comment: Its just a simple method that returns couple of ArrayLists.

Comment: I ask because without knowing what the controller method looks like this is incredibly hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: Matt, give me few. I will post the controller method.

Comment: Matt I added the controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create yyour own Filter by extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`

I don't have the entire code in front of my eyes, but the following article could help you:

http://mark.koli.ch/2010/07/spring-3-and-spring-security-setting-your-own-custom-j-spring-security-check-filter-processes-url.html